# How to Disable WordPress Page Revisions?

Tags: php

I want to disable page revisions in Wordpress without plugin. All are telling about post revisions. i disabled post revisions, can anyone tell me how to disable page revisions in wordpress not post revisions.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Pages and Posts support very similar things. The full list can be [found on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L41). If we want to remove one of these post type features we can use the [`remove_post_type_support()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support):

```
function remove_posttype_supports() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'revisions' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_posttype_supports' );
```

The above you would need to put in your functions.php or as a plugin.